# Postfix NOT WORKING on Port 465 (but working on Port 587)

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

My Postfix Dovecot mail server is working on 587 but not on port 465. I want to use my outlook client. i tried reading the instructions/documentations but nothing helped so far, I checked available solutions but they did not work as well. Not sure what I missed, any help would be appreciated.

Postcon -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
mydestination = $myhostname, kninux.ml, mail.kninux.ml, localhost.kninux.ml, localhost
myhostname = mail.kninux.ml
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.kninux.ml/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.kninux.ml/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtputf8_enable = no
```

Master.cf

```
 Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
 of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
 on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).

 Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.

======
 service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
======
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

 Configuration for port 587
submission     inet     n    -    y    -    -    smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=no
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth

smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

 for Microsoft client  Supports port 465
 Adding specific port
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth

628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
        -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd

 Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
 pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.

 Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
 agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
 and other message envelope options.

 maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
 Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1

 maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}

 Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.

 Specify in cyrus.conf:
   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4

 Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost

 Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
 Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1

cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}

 Old example of delivery via Cyrus.

old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}

 See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.

uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)

 Other external delivery methods.

ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Comment: Your output is broken (multiple lines for `smtps` port). Either post them without removing letters - or just use the commands recommended in the tag description to create a well-formatted version of your config. Also, check the logs generated by postfix when it starts.

Comment: Hi Anx, thanks for sharing your inputs, i will use the suggested format for the future posts. I did some research and found only Outlook client is causing the issue, other clients are working on Port 465. I believe we can close the post here, i will soon delete my post or feel free to close it if possible.

Comment: When you have identified a root cause or potential solution, [on this site](https://serverfault.com/tour) the correct course of action is to ensure that others benefit from the solution as well. Improving the question and writing an answer, or closing as a duplicate of a question that already has your answer is usually much better than removing the question (that would be leaving the next person to wonder about the same thing again)

Comment: @anx sure, I hope this helps people. I would be happy to answer anyone's question. Just to let people know, the above posted configurations is correct, it is the Outlook client that was causing issues; other clients were working just w\fine with this configurations.